# ND4J class-package mappings

Tags: java, maven, nd4j

I am getting the following error while running a program using ND4J:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.nd4j.tools.PropertyParser
```

So far I have the following nd4j artifacts in my pom file:

javacpp, nd4j-jblas, nd4j-native-platform, nd4j-native, nd4j-common following the dependencies mentioned [here](https://nd4j.org/getstarted):

How can I reverse the error message and go from the missing class to the package that would import this class? Thanks

Comment: What does your import in the class look like and can you add that to your post?  Have you checked the documents to make sure you don't have cross dependencies because Maven can't see classes if the dependencies are artifacts that are cross dependent overriding each other?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your Maven repository:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.nd4j/nd4j-api -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>nd4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.3.5.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

You are missing the dependency for your nd4j.  Also, you can recompile.  Here's an article on how to set-up a deep-learning project https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/deeplearning4j-config-maven.

Also, it's a good practice to make sure you check the Mavenrepository if you are missing a dependency.